# Overridden doDML() in EntityImpl does not refresh attributes

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using an Oracle ADF page to update data in a table.  My entity object is based on the table, but I want the DML (inserts, updates, deletes) to go through a package procedure in the database instead of using the default DML generated by the ADF framework.

To accomplish this, I am following Oracle's documentation, found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31974/bcadveo.htm#ADFFD1129

This all works fine.  The problem is, the default ADF DML processing will automatically refresh the entity row after writing it, either with a `RETURNING INTO` clause or with a separately issued `SELECT` statements (depending on the value of `isUseReturningClause()` in the `EntityDefImpl` object).  This is done so that the application front end gets updated in case the row was modified by the database during the DML process (e.g., a `BEFORE ROW` trigger changes values).

But, when I overwrite `doDml()` to replace the default framework DML with a call to my package procedure, it no longer automatically refreshes, even if `isUseReturningClause()` returns false.

I tried adding code to my `doDml()` implementation to requery afterwards, but it didn't work (maybe I didn't do it correctly).  But, Oracle's documentation doesn't say anything about having to do that.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

---

#### Update

I went back to my attempt to have `doDml()` refresh afterwards by calling `doSelect()` and it works.  My original attempt didn't work because `doSelect()` wasn't sending notifications of its changes.

Still, I'm concerned that this isn't how Oracle's documentation says to do it so I have no idea if this is correct or a kludge or a plain bad idea.  So, my original question still stands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged an SR with Oracle.  Their response was that if you override `doDML()` and do not call `super.doDML()` then you lose the automatic refresh functionality of the framework.

They wouldn't comment on my solution, which was to call `doSelect(false)` after any inserts or updates in my `doDML()` override.  Their policy is that if you want advice on customizations, you should engage Oracle Consulting.

Answer (score 0):

**In ADF World** i faced this case and i solve it by simple way , 
firstly it seems bug here , but i can explain what is the expected procedure should be done.
values which set in background[Model layer] in MVC approach should be not edit by user.

solution in 1 word add property of af|inputText disabled="true".